# Integral Border Rule

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

I am currently trying to understand this border rule I never saw in my life. I didnt find it Anywhere else on the internet and I find it very strange.

$\int_{-\infty}^{a} xf(x)dx + \int_{a}^{\infty} xf(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} (y+a)f(y+a)dy + \int_{0}^{\infty} (y+a)f(y+a)dy$

I saw that used in a proof about E[X], with a symmetric destribution around a.
Can some one please explain to me how this is right or give me a source were I can findt it.

Thanks

Comment: it is just a change of variable of integration. Set $y+a=x$ and all is done.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but why does $a$ get replacet with $0$ shouldn't it be $ a = x - y $?

Comment: @DavideTrono or am I thinking wrong? Change of variables mean substitution and the border need to be substituted too or?

Comment: Nope: the value changes because the variable changes. Hence, you search for the $y$ such that $y+a=a$, thus $y=0$